# how to create array inside array from text file in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

first, i have a text file

```
Samsung|us|new
iPhone|china|new
```

i want to convert the text file, and the result must be like this

```
[
    [
        'Samsung', 'us', 'new'
    ],
    [
        'iPhone', 'china', 'new'
    ]
]
```

i have already try this, but the code only return one array

code:

```
<?php
$a = file_get_contents("text.txt");
$b = explode('|', $a);
```

result:

```
[
    'Samsung','us','new','iPhone','china','new'
];
```

Comment: Look into [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) (if your file isn't too big).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `file_get_contents()` reads the whole file including the line breaks.
You have to first `explode()` on `\n`. After that `explode()` on `|`.

Or with `array_map()` in one line:

```
$a = file_get_contents("text.txt");
$b = array_map(fn($line) => explode('|', $line), explode("\n", $a));
                                                                // $a with \n
                                                 // this explode splits the lines
                            // this explodes at the | character
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/24qla

If you want to read some big files you can use something like this:

```
function getCsvData($file, $delimiter = '|') {
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            yield $data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

foreach(getCsvData('test.txt') as $row) {
  print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: `file()` would be basically doing the same as `file_get_contents()` + manual line splitting.

Answer (score 1):

According to the hint from [Jeto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965834/jeto) I would do the following:

at first read the file with function [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) with the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`. This reads the file line by line and creates an array.
next step would be to iterate over each element and split by `|` character with [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

This could be the resulting code:

```
$file = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
for($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++)
{
    $file[$i] = explode('|', $file[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `file_get_contents` open the file and read the file line by line. Then split the line.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Here are some example to do this. You can use `fgets` for this. With `file_get_contents` you get the whole file.

Another solution is to explode by `\r\n` or `\n` the characters for new line. Then you have the single lines and you can split them by your delimiter. But in this case you write the whole content in an array what can cause some memory problem.

```
explode("\n",$homepage)
```